# Advanced filtered search accross multiple sql tables

Tags: sql, database

I'm trying to write a method that would search accross a sql database of people and return the people that matched the search input. The problem is that the search is composed of multiple filters that uses multiple relational tables.

For example lets say I have a table named People and two tables Skills and Preferences (many to one relationship with People) and I want to return a set of people that have certain skills and preferences. What would be the most effecient way to filter over these tables?

To give a practical example:

Lets say the database is set up like this:

```
People
Id, Name
1,  Person1
2,  Person2
3,  Person3
4   Person4

Skills
Id, Person_Id, Skill_Name
1,  1        , Basketball
2,  1        , Tennis
3,  3        , Basketball
4,  4        , Soccer

Preferences
Id, Person_Id, Preference
1,  1        , Hot
2,  1        , Light
3,  2        , Dark
4,  3        , Cold
5,  4        , Warm
```

and I want to return a list of all people that have the skill Basketball and and also have the Preferences Hot and Light (In this case only Person 1), what would be the most effecient way to do this in generic terms?

I am trying to find an efficient way to do this, I can think of a few methods but they seem like bad solutions for this problem as when put in practice there may be quite a few relational tables and I don't want it to take to much time to return the list.

I would appreciate any experience anyone has in this field.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One method is just `exists` for each condition:

```
select p.*
from people p
where exists (select 1
              from skills s
              where s.person_id = p.id and
                    s.skill_name = 'Basketball'
             ) and
      exists (select 1
              from preferences pf
              where pf.person_id = p.id and
                    pf.preference_name = 'Hot'
             ) and
      exists (select 1
              from preferences pf
              where pf.person_id = p.id and
                    pf.preference_name = 'Light'
             ) ;
```